# Icon font inside text input

Tags: css

How to put a awesome icon font inside the bootstrap input type text aligned at left and with some margin-right relative to the placeholder text using bootstrap? Im doing like this: https://jsfiddle.net/tbeay2vd/1/ and using the bootstrap class "input-group-addon" it works but I would like to have a input text like:

[image]

Do you know how to do that using bootstrap?

Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col col-md-7">


      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Search...">
      </div>

    <!-- How to do this input text below using bootstrap ? -->

      <div class="example">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search..
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('input').on('focus', function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.example {
  margin-top:30px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  border-radius:4px;
  padding:15px;
}
.example >i {
  margin-right:10px;
}
.search-input { 
  border: none;
  width: 90%;
}
.search-input:focus{ 
  outline: none;
}
.example.active {
 border-color: #80bdff;
}
.search-box .input-group-addon {
  background: none;
} 
.search-box input {
  border-left: none;
}
.search-box.active .input-group-addon {
  border-color: #80bdff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col col-md-7">

      <div class="input-group search-box">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Search...">
      </div>
    
    <!-- Hpw to do this layout using bootstrap ? -->

      <div class="example">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
          <input type="text" class="search-input" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Search...">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.input-group >.fa{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 37%;
    left: 20px;
}
.input-group .form-control{
    padding-left: 40px;
    height: 60px;
    border: black solid 1px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px!important; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col col-md-7">
       <div class="input-group">
        <i  class="fa fa-search"></i>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Search...">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```